# load spring application context from string

Tags: java, spring

Can somebody show me how to use Spring to load application context through xml string instead of file or classpath resource?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found a way doing it.

```
public MyApplicationContext(String xml,
        ApplicationContext parent){

    super(parent);

    this.configResources = new Resource[1];

    configResources[0] = new ByteArrayResource(xml.getBytes());


    refresh();
}


private Resource[] configResources;

protected Resource[] getConfigResources() {
    return this.configResources;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use this:

```
String contextXML = ...;
Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource(contextXML.getBytes());
GenericXmlApplicationContext springContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
springContext.load(resource);
Object myBean = springContext.getBean("myBean");
...
```

Reza

Comment: You can do it inline too: `GenericXmlApplicationContext springContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext( new ByteArrayResource( contextXML.getBytes() ) );` +1 thanks!

Comment: Using `InMemoryResource` is even shorter: `new GenericXmlApplicationContext(new InMemoryResource(contextXML))`

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it so far but can probably give a try:

```
// define and open the input stream from which we read the configuration
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream("string".getBytes("UTF-8"));
// create the bean factory
DefaultListableBeanFactory beans = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(beans);
reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_XSD);
reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new InputStreamResource(input));
beans.preInstantiateSingletons();
input.close();
```

@Ref: http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/load-spring-from-input-stream/
Let me know if it works...

Comment: thanks, it works but it is not an application context. I need an application context so that i can load it with a parent context. I finally figured out a way to do it.