# How to load application context from string in Spring 2.5?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

As the title says, I want to load some beans from a String.
[This approach only works in Spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480054/load-spring-application-context-from-string) because `GenericXmlApplicationContext` is unavailable in version 2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the approach outlined [here](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/load-spring-from-input-stream/). With one additional step, pass the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` into a `GenericApplicationContext` (this one has been around since Spring 1.1 and the GenericXmlApplicationContext is basically a convenience class doing more or less the same as in that blog post).

So something like this should work

```
String content = ...
GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(ctx);
reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ByteArrayResource(content.getBytes())); 
ctx.refresh();
```

The `ApplicationContext` should now be ready for use.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it myself, but [according to the API documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractXmlApplicationContext.html), you can easily extend the AbstractXmlApplicationContext and implement the `getConfigResources()` method.
You can use the `org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource` to serve as a placeholder for your XML string.